# How use MiR robot's REST APi to move the robot to a specified pose?

Tags: rest, robotics

I am working on the MiR mobile platform and tried to use the REST API to move the robot to a specified coordinate. I am not too sure how to proceed with this as I am new to REST API.

However, I tried connecting to the robot and run an existing mission with predifined coordinate which worked fine.